# Directly providing foreign key value in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

Consider these two models:

```
class CarType(models.Model):
   code_name = models.SlugField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Car(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   car_type = models.ForeignKey('CarType')
```

Assume we want to get all sedan cars, instead of this query:

```
Car.objects.filter(car_type=CarType.objects.get(code_name='sedan'))
```

We can use this query:

```
sedan_cars = Car.objects.filter(car_type__code_name='sedan')
```

Because `code_name` is primary key in `CarType`, the second code won't generate 2 queries (like the first one) or even use an SQL join.

how this can be done in creating `Car` objects? the naive way is like this:

```
Car.objects.create(name='Tesla S', car_type=CarType.objects.get(code_name='sedan'))
```

This will query `CarType` to find out the primary key value of row with criteria `code_name='sedan'` and use that primary key in `car_type` field of `Car` table. Since we already know the primary key value of `CarType` this will be a really unnecessary extra query. (**OR** *is django smart enough to avoid that?*)

How can `car_type` value be provided directly? I tried these two but both failed:

```
Car.objects.create(name='Tesla S', car_type='sedan')
Car.objects.create(name='Tesla S', car_type__code_name='sedan')
```

Comment: I would worry more at the performance impact of not having an incremental primary key  (I'm pretty sure this will make lookup much harder).

Comment: @Sayse but it's semantically more correct...

Comment: I wasn't saying its wrong, I was just saying it might make indexing and lookups less performant, possibly depending on db type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also extra field `car_type_id` which contains raw ID of foreign object. You can write to it when creating new `Car` object. So code:

```
Car.objects.create(name='Tesla S', car_type_id='sedan')
```

Should work fine.

Comment: Note that you can also use that field for lookups.

Answer (score -1):

As you have give `car_type` as foreign key you need to give car object first and then declare `car_type`:

```
c = Car.objects.filter(car_type=CarType.objects.get(code_name='sedan'))
c.car_type = 'sedan'
```